# How to force client trusting in PKCS12 certificate(unable to find valid certification path to requested target)?

Tags: java, spring, windows, https, ssl-certificate

According the [article](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/):

I created PKCS12 certificate and put file **keystore.p12** under the `src/main/respurces`

My spring boot application works fine and I have access to my rest services.
From another spring boot application I do http request:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> mappingTemplateResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(httpsUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()), byte[].class);
```

and this code lead to exception because certificate is not registered.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8801/stub_mapping_template": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at pack.MappingTemplateService.checkForUpdates(MappingTemplateService.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

According the article I tried to type:

> D:\app\src\main\resources>keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12
>   -keystore keystore.p12 Enter keystore password:
>
> Keystore type: PKCS12 Keystore provider: SunJSSE
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> Alias name: tomcat Creation date: Jan 9, 2018 Entry type:
>   PrivateKeyEntry Certificate chain length: 1 Certificate[1](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/): Owner:
>   CN=localhost, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
>   Issuer: CN=localhost, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown,
>   C=Unknown Serial number: 64cd4d27 Valid from: Tue Jan 09 17:56:07 MSK
>   2018 until: Fri Jan 07 17:56:07 MSK 2028 Certificate fingerprints:
>            MD5:  A6:F5:67:EE:87:65:21:62:50:5B:67:AE:63:F6:AE:C0
>            SHA1: B8:F5:F7:7D:8C:4C:90:0E:BA:CE:9D:22:3A:D3:A7:6E:BB:12:1B:D8
>            SHA256: 35:B5:DF:15:FC:3B:DD:D3:05:58:88:92:00:47:8F:62:2C:97:D7:20:77:FA:7D:55:00:64:E9:62:F4:7D:3B:08
>            Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
>            Version: 3
>
> Extensions:
>
> ## 1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 3E D4 2D F8 AF D2 C2 4E   51 4F 3E A4 01 FE E2
>
> 34  >.-....NQO>....4 0010: 48 B0 5F 4F
>   H._O ] ]
>
> ---

looks like I should not export certificate explicitly because I use PKCS12 certificate.

How to fix my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue:

1. Registered bean:

   ```
   @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
   private Resource keyStore;
   @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
   private String keyStorePassword;

   @Bean
   RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
       SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
               .loadTrustMaterial(
                       keyStore.getURL(),
                       keyStorePassword.toCharArray()
               ).build();
       SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =
               new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
       HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
               .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
       HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
               new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
       return new RestTemplate(factory);
   }
   ```

2.Added to `application.properties`:

```
# The format used for the keystore
server.ssl.key-store-type:PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat

http.client.ssl.trust-store=classpath:keystore.p12
http.client.ssl.trust-store-password=password
```